# Sticker App : UnsatisfiedLinkError after releasing app AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, webp

I am getting error as I got following crash from Play Console.

Its sticker application and I just updated, before that I have updated many times but didn't get any error.

In this updates I just changed assets folder by adding one folder with 25 images.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:353)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:245)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.b (Unknown Source:254)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source:106)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source:94)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.a (Unknown Source:1)
  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.d.a (Unknown Source:20)
  at com.facebook.animated.webp.WebPImage.a (Unknown Source)
  at com.wastickers.stickers.j.a (Unknown Source:17)
  at com.wastickers.stickers.j.a (Unknown Source:19)
  at com.wastickers.stickers.j.a (Unknown Source:467)
  at com.wastickers.stickers.i.a (Unknown Source:109)
  at com.wastickers.stickers.EntryActivity$a.a (Unknown Source:11)
  at com.wastickers.stickers.EntryActivity$a.doInBackground (Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:333)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
```

I am following this [repository](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/) to make this app.

**build.gradle:** you can also [check here](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.12.0'
}
```

Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle file? Also, do you use anything like Instant Run?

Comment: Yes, I am using Instant Run but I am getting error after publishing app.

Comment: Try upgrading gradle to `4.10.1`

Comment: Okay but every time I need to upload apk for testing? Is there any confirm answer?

Comment: You do realize you can simply run production .apks locally without uploading...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I know that. signed apk is working, but not working when I download from playstore only dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got the solution:

As per this [comment](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/issues/413#issuecomment-460343022) the problem with fresco, where app bundle is not well supported.

> The problem was that app bundle builds multiple dexes, but Fresco was
>   only looking at one to find the so file. There were no problems with
>   using apk to send to play store.

From that link I found to update following libraries.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.12.0'
```

## Update:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.12.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.12.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.12.1'
```

For Me, Following version worked.

Reference Link:

https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/issues/410

https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/issues/413